# Guaranteed Semaphore order?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, semaphore

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore#remarks) for the .NET `Semaphore` class states that:

> There is no guaranteed order, such as FIFO or LIFO, in which blocked threads enter the semaphore.

In this case, if I want a guaranteed order (either FIFO or LIFO), what are my options? Is this something that just isn't easily possible?  Would I have to write my own `Semaphore`? I assume that would be pretty advanced.

Comment: Related: [How to create a FIFO/strong semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415708/how-to-create-a-fifo-strong-semaphore).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this](https://github.com/pvgoran/dcutilities-codeplex-archive/blob/c414fc5d518acd3189945a3c895c376293edc575/sourceCode/dcutilities/Bcl/Concurrency/FifoSemaphore.cs):

> The `FifoSemaphore` works exactly like a normal `Semaphore` but also guarantees that tokens are served out to acquirers in the order that they manage to acquire the internal lock. The usage of a `FifoSemaphore` is identical to a `Semaphore`.

Comment: CodePlex that hosted this library is going to shut down, so I made a (not-quite-good) copy of it at https://github.com/pvgoran/dcutilities-codeplex-archive . Maybe it will be useful to someone.

Comment: The [linked implementation](https://github.com/pvgoran/dcutilities-codeplex-archive/blob/c414fc5d518acd3189945a3c895c376293edc575/sourceCode/dcutilities/Bcl/Concurrency/FifoSemaphore.cs) has not identical API. For example the `Wait` method is named `Acquire`. It also lacks asynchronous capabilities. There is no `AcquireAsync` method analogous to the built-in [`SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync).