# How to create a FIFO/strong semaphore

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency

I need to code my own FIFO/strong semaphore in C#, using a semaphore class of my own as a base. I found [this example](https://code.google.com/p/seacowdb/source/browse/trunk/DLRDB.Core/ConcurrencyUtils/FIFOSemaphore.cs?r=29), but it's not quite right since I'm not supposed to be using Monitor.Enter/Exit yet.

These are the methods for my regular semaphore, and I was wondering if there was a simple way to adapt it to be FIFO.

```
public virtual void Acquire()
{

    lock (this)
    {

        while (uintTokens == 0)
        {

            Monitor.Wait(this);

        }

        uintTokens--;

    }

}

public virtual void Release(uint tokens = 1)
{

    lock (this)
    {

        uintTokens += tokens;
        Monitor.PulseAll(this);

    }

}
```

Comment: Not quite pertinent to your question, but you may want to avoid using `lock(this)` code pattern as it can lead to deadlocks.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/251668/1556108

Comment: Must you be using semaphore? How about a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`

Comment: Do you mean to use ConcurrentQueue as a base? The teacher wanted us to make all the utilities for ourselves, so we don't use any inbuilt concurrency tools. I have my own Channel class though.

Thanks for the tip LB2, the teacher had no problem with it but I'll get around to changing it anyway.

Comment: I checked the source code of [`SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/SemaphoreSlim.cs.html#4772c1d9756a4a9a), and it seems that it is FIFO already. Each task created for the awaiting is stored in a queue implemented as a double linked list.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias SemaphoreSlim and Semaphore are **not** FIFO, as [explicitly mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/semaphore-and-semaphoreslim) in the documentation: _There is no guaranteed order, such as first-in, first-out (FIFO) or last-in, first-out (LIFO), for blocked threads to enter the semaphore._

Comment: @alelom you are right, according to the official documentation the `SemaphoreSlim` is not guaranteed to be FIFO. Microsoft is known to avoid guaranteeing behaviors of existing implementations ([example 1](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46374), [example 2](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72806)). They want to be as free as possible to improve the .NET code base. In practice though they are extremely conservative, and they (almost) never make improvements that can cause behavioral changes ([example](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/84163)).

Comment: I think this has little to do with Microsoft's code policies. AFAIK, semaphores are simply not concerned with _guaranteeing_ the order of waking up from wait, although it's "nearly-FIFO" in order to avoid starvation. For example, [Java's semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) talks about _fairness_ (kind of FIFO, but allows _barging in_ and an _unfair_ configuration). See also e.g. discussion on [C++ `std::binary_semaphore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68703840/does-the-c-stdbinary-semaphore-guarantee-fifo).

Comment: @alelom I should make it clear that my [original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415708/how-to-create-a-fifo-strong-semaphore?noredirect=1#comment109986659_23415708) was about the asynchronous method `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` on .NET Framework. I checked the implementation of this method, and I found it to be FIFO. It is still FIFO [on .NET 8](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/SemaphoreSlim.cs#L595). I am making no claim about the synchronous `SemaphoreSlim.Wait` method, or about similar components in Java.

Comment: @alelom to be more precise, I am claiming that the `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` has FIFO behavior because the pending tasks are stored in an internal double-linked-list with head and tail. Before updating this structure though, the current thread first acquires a `lock`, which is [**not** guaranteed to be FIFO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228864/does-lock-guarantee-acquired-in-order-requested). So the FIFO behavior is only macroscopic (at the granularity level of high latency asynchronous operations). At a microscopic level (nanoseconds) it's not guaranteed to be FIFO.

Answer (score 28):

So `SemaphoreSlim` gives us a good starting place, so we'll begin by wrapping one of those in a new class, and directing everything but the wait method to that semaphore.

To get a queue like behavior we'll want a queue object, and to make sure it's safe in the face of multithreaded access, we'll use a `ConcurrentQueue`.

In this queue we'll put `TaskCompletionSource` objects.  When we want to have something start waiting it can create a TCS, add it to the queue, and then inform the semaphore to asynchronously pop the next item off of the queue and mark it as "completed" when the wait finishes.  We'll know that there will always be an equal or lesser number of continuations as there are items in the queue.

Then we just wait on the `Task` from the TCS.

We can also trivially create a `WaitAsync` method that returns a task, by just returning it instead of waiting on it.

```
public class SemaphoreQueue
{
    private SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
    private ConcurrentQueue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> queue =
        new ConcurrentQueue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();
    public SemaphoreQueue(int initialCount)
    {
        semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount);
    }
    public SemaphoreQueue(int initialCount, int maxCount)
    {
        semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount, maxCount);
    }
    public void Wait()
    {
        WaitAsync().Wait();
    }
    public Task WaitAsync()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        queue.Enqueue(tcs);
        semaphore.WaitAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<bool> popped;
            if (queue.TryDequeue(out popped))
                popped.SetResult(true);
        });
        return tcs.Task;
    }
    public void Release()
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of things in there that we haven't been taught, which means that we're not really meant to use them. Wait, for example. Also, I have my own Channel class (thread-safe queue), which I suppose can be used.

Comment: @FreddieAppsHero You're welcome to follow the same model using your own tools, if you prefer.

Comment: My own semaphores lacks WaitAsync, and it'd probably be frowned upon to extend it any more.

Comment: @FreddieAppsHero That's certainly your decision to make.

Comment: Note that when a Task becomes completed as a result of SetResult, the TaskScheduler might decide to inline the execution, or schedule the execution. E.g. you have no real FIFO guarantee with this implementation I believe. Came here, because I built something similar, which I believe doesn't have the strong FIFO guarantee either.

Comment: @Tohnmeister Indeed, doing a simple test this is not working as expected

Comment: I confirm that after testing this repeatedly it doesn't seem to consistently behave as FIFO. I'm adding a link to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2554069/3873799) for another implementation (which I haven't tested yet).

Answer (score 1):

I have created a FifoSemaphore class and I am successfully using it in my solutions. Current limitation is that it behaves like a Semaphore(1, 1).

```
public class FifoSemaphore
{
    private readonly object lockObj = new object();

    private List<Semaphore> WaitingQueue = new List<Semaphore>();


    private Semaphore RequestNewSemaphore()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            Semaphore newSemaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1);
            newSemaphore.WaitOne();
            return newSemaphore;
        }
    }

    #region Public Functions

    public void Release()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            WaitingQueue.RemoveAt(0);
            if (WaitingQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                WaitingQueue[0].Release();
            }
        }
    }

    public void WaitOne()
    {
        Semaphore semaphore = RequestNewSemaphore();
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            WaitingQueue.Add(semaphore);
            semaphore.Release();

            if(WaitingQueue.Count > 1)
            {
                semaphore.WaitOne();
            }
        }
        semaphore.WaitOne();

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Usage is just like with a regular semaphore:

```
FifoSemaphore fifoSemaphore = new FifoSemaphore();
```

On each thread:

```
fifoSemaphore.WaitOne();
//do work
fifoSemaphore.Release();
```

Comment: Is there specific reason why you didn't use ConcurrentQueue or any Queue for that matter at all?