# Ordered execution of methods given they haven't been fired in order

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have two asynchronous methods (let's call them `AAsync()` and `BAsync()`) that are intended to run one after the other one. This is because method `AAsync()` prepares the context for method `BAsync()` to act properly. For each call of `AAsync()` there's a correspondent call of the method `BAsync()`.

These methods can be fired in the following order (as an example):

**A<sub>1</sub>A<sub>2</sub>B<sub>1</sub>B<sub>2</sub>A<sub>3</sub>B<sub>3</sub>B<sub>4</sub>A<sub>4</sub>**, where A stands for `AAsync`, B for `BAsync`, and the subindex indicates the call number of the method.

Given that it will always be that method AAsync<sub>i</sub> will be called after method AAsync<sub>i-1</sub> and before AAsync<sub>i+1</sub> (same applies for BAsync), and that a call AAsync<sub>i</sub> has a correspondant call BAsync<sub>i</sub>, I would like to know which is the best way to, given a disordered firing of the methods (like the one in the example above), execute the calls in the following order:

**A<sub>1</sub>B<sub>1</sub>A<sub>2</sub>B<sub>2</sub>A<sub>3</sub>B<sub>3</sub>A<sub>4</sub>B<sub>4</sub> ...**

I have solved this using two [FIFO Semaphores](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23415880/13839278) and two `TaskCompletionSource` (see below), but I have the feeling that this can be solved in a smarter way. Does anybody know a nicer solution?

```c#
TaskCompletionSource TCS_A;
TaskCompletionSource TCS_B;

FIFOSemaphore MutexA = new FIFOSemaphore(1);
FIFOSemaphore MutexB = new FIFOSemaphore(1);

async void AAsync()
{
    await MutexA.WaitAsync();

    if (TCS_B!= null)
        await TCS_B.Task;

    TCS_B = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    // Do intended stuff...

    TCS_A?.TrySetResult(true);

    MutexA.Release();
}

async void BAsync()
{
    await MutexB.WaitAsync();

    if (TCS_A!= null)
        await TCS_A.Task;
            
    TCS_A = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    // Do intended stuff...

    TCS_B?.TrySetResult(true);

    MutexB.Release();
}
```

Comment: As a side note, `async void` methods are intended mainly for event handlers, and generally [should be avoided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Comment: Yes, I didn't put it just to simplify, but they are event handlers. Thanks for the note though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use two [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) instances. The channel A should receive the arguments passed to the A event handler, and the channel B should receive the arguments passed to the B event handler. Finally perform an asynchronous loop that takes one item from the channel A and one from the channel B ad infinitum:

```
Channel<EventArgs> _channelA = Channel.CreateUnbounded<EventArgs>();
Channel<EventArgs> _channelB = Channel.CreateUnbounded<EventArgs>();

void EventA_Handler(EventArgs e)
{
    _channelA.Writer.TryWrite(e);
}

void EventB_Handler(EventArgs e)
{
    _channelB.Writer.TryWrite(e);
}

async void EventHandlerLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        EventArgs a = await _channelA.Reader.ReadAsync();
        // Do intended stuff...
        EventArgs b = await _channelB.Reader.ReadAsync();
        // Do intended stuff...
    }
}
```

The method `EventHandlerLoop` should be invoked during the initialization of the class, to start the wheel rolling.

If you are not familiar with the channels, you could take a look at [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) tutorial.

Comment: I didn't know about the existence of `Channel<T>`, thanks! Looks pretty much what I was looking for.
Wouldn't be possible as well to include the content of the `while(true)` directly on `EventB_Handler`, below the writing to `_channelB`, in order to avoid the `EventHandlerLoop`?

Comment: @Miguel maybe, but it would not be equally robust. The loop approach guarantees that the processing will happen sequentially in the intended order. Without a loop you have to make further assumptions about how the events are fired, and how the `Channel<T>` behaves when consumed by multiple consumers.