# Does the C++ std::binary_semaphore guarantee FIFO?

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore, fifo

I am looking to use `std::binary_semaphore` to make sure that threads are processed in the order in which they entered the semaphore.

I know that semaphore queues are typically FIFO, but I am not able to guarantee that C++'s implementation is FIFO.

Is the C++ `std::binary_semaphore` FIFO? In other words, does it wake threads in the order in which they came in?

Comment: If two threads are waiting on `acquire`, how would you observe which one came first?
On libstdc++, `binary_semaphore` seems to be using futex, which does not provide any guarantee regarding which thread gets waken up on release.

Comment: I think it is implementation-defined. MSVC implementation is based on `WaitOnAddress` API, which is nearly FIFO.

Comment: The order in which suspended threads will resume their activity is not guaranteed. Anyway, an algorithm that tries to predict in which order threads will be executed is a terrible design. Just don't do that.

Comment: I think there are many cases where we absolutely want each thread to be processed FIFO. I'm working on a robot design where the perception pipeline may take longer than a single loop, and so it becomes necessary to run the perception pipeline in the background and use a semaphore to make sure the sensor readings are processed by the pipeline in the order in which they enter the pipeline.

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792016/creating-a-lock-that-preserves-the-order-of-locking-attempts-in-c11  Basically it something you need write on top of the provided primitives unless your OS can give some type of guarantee.

Comment: Even if you wake up your threads in FIFO order, there's no guarantee that a thread won't be pre-empted immediately after being waken up. It seems that you want to setup priorities, you might want something like `sched_setscheduler(SCHED_FIFO)`

Comment: @Attra 'I think there are many cases where we absolutely want each thread to be processed FIFO' ok, don't use one semaphore.