# A fair semaphore in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, semaphore

I'm using a semaphore to control access of multiple concurrent threads.

It would be nice if the semaphore could preferably enable those threads that have waited the longest, instead of just randomly picking one. In other words, it should have some notion of *fairness*.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) on semaphores mentions they are not fair:

> There is no guaranteed order, such as FIFO or LIFO, in which blocked threads enter the semaphore.

How should I go about creating such a semaphore?

Comment: The MSDN docs state it is *not* fair for `SemaphoreSlim`: "there is no guaranteed order, such as FIFO or LIFO, that controls when threads enter the semaphore." See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553982/guaranteed-semaphore-order) for potential solutions.

Comment: @vcsjones I'm using a regular `Semaphore`, but that's good to know.

Comment: @vcsjones Oh, I just noticed it does mention the same for the regular one, too! I missed that.

Comment: it also says that for the Win32 semaphore APIs, which `Semaphore` is just a wrapper around. " Do not assume a first-in, first-out (FIFO) order" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @vcsjones Thank you. I've edited the question to how to create such a semaphore, seeing you already answered my initial question! :)